# Why won't page elements stay hidden when printing?

Tags: css, printing

I have a web site I am working on where I have a 'print page' button. When the page prints, I
want to hide certain elements of the page (e.g. left hand nav, top nav, etc...).

I have added this to my style.css:

```
@media print {
  #topnav { display:none }
  #left-col { display:none }
}
```

However, when I go to look at the print preview of the page, those elements are still there.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I do print preview here with Firefox 14 and Chrome Latest: http://jsfiddle.net/gQfJn/embedded/result/ ([editable version](http://jsfiddle.net/gQfJn/)) And it's hidden. (IE9 print preview doesn't show anything? But thinks there's two pages?) You'll need to provide more information and most preferably a working demonstration of your problem.

Comment: I figured out what was causing the problem. I had media=screen as part of my style.css call. Once I removed that, it worked great!

Comment: Post that as the answer (with a description of what happened and your faulty markup), so that later users can see how you "fixed" it.

Comment: Make sure and mark it as the answer when it lets you (after so long, not sure how long).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. It was a coding error on my part. My original link to my stylesheet
looked like this:

```
<link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

and was causing a conflict. Once I removed `media="screen"` it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

***HTML CODE***

```
<input type="submit" id="print" value="Submit">
```

***JS CODE***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#print').on('click', function(){
        $('selector i.e #leftnav, #topnav').die();
     });
  });
```

***OR***

```
$('selector i.e #leftnav, #topnav').hide();
```

Comment: Oh no. First, there is no need for Javascript to resolve the specific problem. Second, Javascript isn't even suggested. Third, a jQuery-based answer is unnecessary and dramatic overkill for this problem.